# Prove couple of facts about subspace and intersection of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Prove if $\mathcal {W\subseteq V}$ then $\dim(\mathcal W)\le \dim(\mathcal V)$

$\mathcal W\subseteq \mathcal V$ means for some $W\subseteq V$ where $V$ comes from a vector space $\mathcal V=(V,\circ)$ with $\circ$ denoting the axpy operator ($ax+y$), $\mathcal W=(\text{span}(W),\circ)$. $\dim(\cdot)$ is defined as maximum number of linearly independent vectors in vector space $\cdot$. So since $W\subseteq V$ the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in $\text{span}(W)$ *is* the number of linearly independent vectors in $W$, which must be no more than in $V$.

> Prove $\dim(\mathcal {V\cap W})\le\min(\dim(\mathcal V), \dim(\mathcal W))$

If $\mathcal V=(V,\circ),\mathcal W=(W,\circ)$ then $\mathcal {V\cap W}=(V\cap W,\circ)$ [by the definition I have]. Since the number of linearly independent vectors in $V\cap W$ can't be more than in $V$
or $W$ (and could be less) the result holds.

Have I made any false statements? I'm not too convinced even by my own reasoning for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea for the first statement, but you have phrased your proof in a confusing (and arguably incorrect) way. Here's an alternative proof.

Let $S = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathcal W$ with $n = \dim(\mathcal W)$; such a set exists by the definition of dimension. It follows that $S$ is a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathcal V$. Thus, the maximum possible size of a linearly independent set in $\mathcal V$ is at least $n = \dim(\mathcal W)$, which is to say that $\dim \mathcal V \geq \dim \mathcal W$.

For the second statement, simply apply the first statement noting that we have $\mathcal V \cap \mathcal W \subseteq \mathcal V$ and $\mathcal V \cap \mathcal W \subseteq \mathcal W$.

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to prove it starting with $n$ linearly independent vectors from $\mathcal V$ and then sort of shrinking the set to be linearly independent in $\mathcal W$?

Comment: Say $T=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathcal V$ and $\dim\mathcal V=m$. Since $\text{span} W\subseteq V$ then $\{v_{i_1},v_{i_2},\dots,v_{i_k}\}\subseteq T; k\le m$ is maximally linearly independent in $\mathcal W$.

Do you think this is right?

Comment: @Jellyfish No, that's not right. If the vectors of $T$ are only specified to be elements of $\mathcal V$, we have no reason to assume that they are also elements of $\mathcal W$

Comment: you are so right! I guess the way you did it is the way to go